# Optional Argument: compile time constant issue

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-errors

Why is this working:

```
public int DoesEmailAddressExistsExcludingEmailAddressID(
    string emailAddress, 
    string invitationCode, 
    int emailAddressID = 0, 
    int For = (int) Enums.FOR.AC)
```

whereas this doesn't

```
public int DoesEmailAddressExistsExcludingEmailAddressID(
    string emailAddress, 
    string invitationCode, 
    int emailAddressID = 0, 
    int For = Enums.FOR.AC.GetHashCode())
```

where AC is enum. Can enums's hashcode change at runtime?

Comment: GetHashCode() requires executing code.  Which means it is not a compile time constant.

Comment: The solution for this problem, by the way, is to use the classic C# overloading approach, rather than using default arguments.

Comment: I strongly suggest not using `For` as a variable name.  The first example `as is` would not actually compile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`GetHashCode` is a method. The return value of a method is not a compile time constant as code needs to be executed to determine the return value.
It doesn't matter whether or not the method returns always the same.

Answer (score 2):

There is a good chance that an Enum's hash code remains constant during a program's runtime. However, this is not *guaranteed* at compile time. Therefore it cannot be a compile-time constant.

Moreover, as Daniel already mentioned, `GetHashCode` has to be executed to determine the value, which can obviously not be done at compile-time.

Comment: +1 for a good point: in practice we know that it's virtually certain that an enum's hash code will always be the same, but *it's not guaranteed*, so the compiler has to treat the method call like any other.